# How to restrict the answer size in javamail search method?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am using `Javamail` library to fetch emails from several servers through IMAP.
I only care for the unread messages and I want to download only the 5 last received unread messages.

For filtering the messages in a folder I am using using the `Folder.search(FlagTerm ft)` method passing the flag `SEEN` with value false, just as following code shows:

```
FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
Message[] messages = folder.search(ft);
```

I need to diminish bandwidth usage and the above method may return an arbitrarily large number of messages. I am only interested in the last 5 of them, is there a way for the IMAP server return a limited number of messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the search over a subset of the messages, effectively setting an upper limit on the number of messages returned, but you might have to do multiple searches.  There's no direct way to limit the number of results returned if you're searching all messages.

Note that the search results are relatively compact (effectively only the message number), so unless you're searching a huge number of messages I wouldn't think bandwidth would be an issue relative to fetching the content of the messages.